# Rvest webscrape error for all attempts

Tags: r, rvest

When I scrape imdb.com according to tutorial on rbloggers, I am able to get all the values.
When I want to scrape https://www.pelikan.sk/sk/deals/list it shows `Error: No matches` for all attempts

My code:
For extracting the header

```
pelikansk = read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
pelikansk %>% 
html_node("h2 .ng-binding") %>%
html_text()
```

For extracting the price:

```
pelikansk %>% 
html_node(".ng-scope+ .ng-binding") %>%
html_text()
```

For extracting the discount:

```
pelikansk %>% 
html_node(".save .ng-binding") %>%
html_text()
```

It shows same error for all attempts. I guess the html_node is correct for all. Can you pls suggest, what causes problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as far as I understand, we cannot extract the data you want directly, since the html file itself does not contain the information. Try to `Inspect` or `View page source` (if you use Chrome; similar function should  also be available in others) and you can see what I mean.

Comment: I see, thanks!
Btw, do you know any way, how this site can be scraped with R?

Comment: First you need to find out where the data you're looking for is located. If it includes browsing through the web and you want to automate it, probably you can check `RSelenium` package

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the headers with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.pelikan.sk/sk/deals/list')

web_Obj_Accept <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="ngAppContainer"]/div[4]/div/div[3]/button[3]')
web_Obj_Accept$clickElement()

list_Web_Obj_Content_Wrap <- remDr$findElements('class name', "offer-content-wrap")
list_Text_Header <- lapply(X = list_Web_Obj_Content_Wrap, FUN = function(x) x$getElementText()[[1]])
unlist(list_Text_Header)[1 : 10]

[1] "Dubaj-3*Ibis Styles Jumeira (hotel bez letenky)\nJumeirah Beach\nmeal\nbedstay"                                                                 
[2] "Dubaj-4*Hilton Garden Inn Dubai Al Mina (hotel bez letenky)\nstrešný bazén / mestský hotel\nmeal\nbedstay"                                      
[3] "Abu Dhabi-4*Aloft Abu Dhabi (hotel bez letenky)\nubytovanie v 4* hoteli s raňajkami\nmeal\nbedstay"                                             
[4] "Dubaj-4*Zabeel House by Jumeirah, The Greens (hotel bez letenky)\nmódna štvrť Internet City / raňajky\nmeal\nbedstay"                           
[5] "3*Strachan Family Jasná s raňajkami\nDemänovská Dolina\nbedstay\nmeal\nwellness\ncarpark"                                                       
[6] "Abu Dhabi-4*TRYP by Wyndham City Center (hotel bez letenky)\nhotel v centre mesta s raňajkami\nmeal\nbedstay"                                   
[7] "Dubaj-4*Hilton Dubai The Walk (hotel bez letenky)\nDubai Marina\nmeal\nbedstay"                                                                 
[8] "Abu Dhabi-5*Le Méridien (hotel bez letenky)\nluxusný hotel / priamo na pláži\nmeal\nbedstay"                                                    
[9] "Abu Dhabi-5*Radisson Blu Abu Dhabi Corniche (hotel bez letenky)\nluxusný hotel / priamo na pláži\nmeal\nbedstay"                                
[10] "Holiday Village Tatralandia Apartmán DELUXE s raňajkami\nzrekonštruované Chatky DELUXE pre maximálne pohodie\nbedstay\nmeal\nwellness\ncarpark"
```